# More than one views (inflaters) in one Adapter

Tags: java, android, adapter

How to use two different views in one Adapter? I need 3 fields from one layout and 4-th fields from other.

This code works fine if I have only 1-5 items at the screen (extends Base adapter):

```
@Override
public View getView (final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
FieldsAndText p = getFields(position);

view = convertView;
    if (position != 3) {
      if (view == null) {
        view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.addproduct_item, parent, false);
      }
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.addProductTextView)).setText(p.name);
    EditText editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.addProductEditText);
    editText.setText(p.value);
    }
    else if (position == 3) {
      if (view == null) {
        view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.alternative_item, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.alternative_textView1);
      }
    }
    return view;
}
```

But when there's more then 5 items and I make scroll down, I have an error:

> Null pointer exception in:     ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.addProductTextView)).setText(p.name);

Comment: https://edisonthk.wordpress.com/2014/06/12/constraints-of-multiple-layouts-listview-for-android/ it will helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType()` to teach the `AdapterView` about your multiple types of rows.

For example, here is an activity with a `ListAdapter` that has separate layouts for headers and details:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2008-2012 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain   a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    http://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.headerdetail;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HeaderDetailListDemo extends ListActivity {
  private static final String[][] items= {
      { "lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet" },
      { "consectetuer", "adipiscing", "elit", "morbi", "vel" },
      { "ligula", "vitae", "arcu", "aliquet", "mollis" },
      { "etiam", "vel", "erat", "placerat", "ante" },
      { "porttitor", "sodales", "pellentesque", "augue", "purus" } };

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setListAdapter(new IconicAdapter());
  }

  class IconicAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
      int count=0;

      for (String[] batch : items) {
        count+=1 + batch.length;
      }

      return(count);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
      int offset=position;
      int batchIndex=0;

      for (String[] batch : items) {
        if (offset == 0) {
          return(Integer.valueOf(batchIndex));
        }

        offset--;

        if (offset < batch.length) {
          return(batch[offset]);
        }

        offset-=batch.length;
        batchIndex++;
      }

      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid position: "
          + String.valueOf(position));
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
      return(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
      return(2);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
      if (getItem(position) instanceof Integer) {
        return(0);
      }

      return(1);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      if (getItemViewType(position) == 0) {
        return(getHeaderView(position, convertView, parent));
      }

      View row=convertView;

      if (row == null) {
        row=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
      }

      ViewHolder holder=(ViewHolder)row.getTag();

      if (holder == null) {
        holder=new ViewHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
      }

      String word=(String)getItem(position);

      if (word.length() > 4) {
        holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.delete);
      }
      else {
        holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ok);
      }

      holder.label.setText(word);
      holder.size.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.size_template),
                                        word.length()));

      return(row);
    }

    private View getHeaderView(int position, View convertView,
                               ViewGroup parent) {
      View row=convertView;

      if (row == null) {
        row=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, parent, false);
      }

      Integer batchIndex=(Integer)getItem(position);
      TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.label);

      label.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.batch),
                                  1 + batchIndex.intValue()));

      return(row);
    }
  }
}
```

`getViewTypeCount()` returns `2`, as I have two types of rows. `getItemViewType()` returns `0` for header rows and `1` for detail rows, based on the results of a `getItem()` method that has `Integer` as the model data for headers and a `String` from my array-of-arrays as the model data for detail rows.